# Language switcher - Javascript/jQuery and Cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

Using both internet and Stack Overflow resources I managed to write a crude HTML website, that allows the user to switch Language of it on the fly, using Javascript, jQuery and XML.

Now, the problem I ran into is to keep the preferred language across the entire portal, without the need to change it each time when navigating through it. I have decided to use a simple cookie to keep the track of it, but it seems I have messed something up, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Basically speaking, the page itself has text in the code itself (as a backup just in case), however the text becomes invisible when booting the site, until I switch a language, nor the language is kept when I navigate the portal. For the former, I assumed that the script was reading some empty or overall wrong cookie, so I made an attempt to filter it out and use a default language, but in vain. As for the latter issue, I guess I save the cookie itself wrong as well, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

```
function changeLanguage(lang) {
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'jezyki.xml',
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('translation').each(function(){
                        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                        var text = $(this).find(lang).text();
                        $("." + id).html(text);

                       if (lang === "") { }

                        else {
                            var title = lang;
                            createCookie("language", title, 365);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='radio-language']").click(function () {
        changeLanguage($(this).val());
    });
});

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

window.onload = function (e) {
    var cookie = readCookie("language");
    var domyslny = "english";
    if (title === "") { changeLanguage(domyslny); } else { changeLanguage(title); }
}
```

Apologies if this is something silly, I am quite a newbie when it comes to Javascript/jQuery.